# Let E be a non-meager subset of a Banach space, then E - E contains a neighborhood of zero.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, baire-category

I want to prove the statement:

*Let E be a non-meager subset of a Banach space, then E - E contains a neighborhood of zero.*

Here, *E - E* means the Minkowski difference of *E* with itself. The statement is very similar to a statement about subsets with positive measure. I think I need to use the Baire Category Theorem, but I am not sure how.

Comment: Each infinite dimensional Banach space $X$ contains a dense hyperplane which is of second category (i.e. non-meager) in $X$, and even in itself (see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4342246/is-an-nvs-complete-iff-it-is-non-meagre/4342281#4342281 ).  Taking such a hyperplane for $E$ we have $E-E=E$ which does not contain a neighborhood of zero. In the book of Oxtoby you can find the result you want under the additional assumption that $E$ is the symmetric difference of an open set and a set of first category (Thm 4.8).